# CppUnit leakage

Tags: c++, valgrind, cppunit

running my regression tests with valgrind I have this kind of report:

```
==20341== 256 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 915 of 919                                                                                                         
==20341==    at 0x4A0661C: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:220)                                                                                                      
==20341==    by 0x7F366FA: std::vector<CppUnit::Test*, std::allocator<CppUnit::Test*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CppUnit::Test**, std::vector<CppUnit::Test*, std::allocator<CppUnit::Test*> > >, CppUnit::Test* const&) (new_allocator.h:88)                                                                                                            
==20341==    by 0x7F36496: CppUnit::TestSuite::addTest(CppUnit::Test*) (stl_vector.h:610)                                                                                             
==20341==    by 0x585B80: TestVectorAlgebra::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) (testvectoralgebra.h:30)                                                          
==20341==    by 0x586719: TestVectorAlgebra::suite() (testvectoralgebra.h:42)                                                                                                         
==20341==    by 0x5948C4: CppUnit::TestSuiteFactory<TestVectorAlgebra>::makeTest() (TestSuiteFactory.h:20)                                                                            
==20341==    by 0x7F2C6B0: CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::addTestToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuite*) (TestFactoryRegistry.cpp:149)                                                            
==20341==    by 0x7F2CAD5: CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::makeTest() (TestFactoryRegistry.cpp:136)                                                                                     
==20341==    by 0x580760: main (testunit.cpp:88)
```

I guess this is due the fact that Tests added to Suite are not removed before the main is over.

This is the way I register the test:

```
  CppUnit::TextTestRunner::TestRunner runner;

  // Get the top level suite from the registry
  CppUnit::Test* myTest = 
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest();

  runner.addTest( myTest->findTest("TestVectorAlgebra") );
```

How do I unregister those tests ?

Comment: I diagnosed this leak as well with some windows memory profilers as well. I find CppUnit to be way way way over-engineered. In other words it's a load of garbage.

Answer (score 2):

The [CppUnit documentation](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/1.11.6/class_test_runner.html#a2) suggests that `runner.addTest` takes ownership of whatever test it's given.  By giving `runner.addTest` only part of your myTest instance, you're not providing any way for the entire myTest instance to get cleaned up on deletion.  Manually `delete`'ing myTest after running probably won't work either, since `runner` will also try to delete the portion of `myTest` that it's been given.

If you're interested in only running a particular test or subset of tests, you should instead try using the `testName` parameter of [TextRunner::run](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/1.11.6/class_text_test_runner.html#a2).

(And if you have the time and inclination, you might want to look into a different unit test framework.  [UnitTest++](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp) and [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) are newer, easier to use, and more featureful than CppUnit.)

Comment: TextRunner::run doesn't work if I do not register the suite for the test I want to run.

Comment: Yes, but your problem is that you allocate an entire suite (myTest) and then only register a part of it.  TextRunner cleans up that part but doesn't know to clean up the entire suite.

Comment: Even if I do runner.addTest(myTest); then I have the same behave, lot of suites not destroyed.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to tell you; sorry.  I get correct behavior when I run a very simple CppUnit program through Valgrind; maybe there's a bug in the version of CppUnit you're using, or maybe the leak is in code you haven't posted.  It's been a little while since I've used CppUnit; we switched everything to Google Test.

Comment: I had a quick look at Google Test, it should not be hard to migrate our tests, the hardest stuff is the fact that we use our own TextOutputter (extends CppUnit::TextOutputter) and our own TestListener (extends CppUnit::TestListener ). Thank you for the hint.

Comment: UnitTest++ is no more on sourceforge, but [on github](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp).

Comment: Thanks, @Fil. In the future, feel free to suggest an edit yourself if you have an updated link.

Comment: You're right... I forget I have this functionality available :P I'll keep in mind for the future. Thank you